# Typeahead's items don't appear

Tags: dojo, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm integrating dojo-bootstrap's typeahead (https://github.com/xsokev/Dojo-Bootstrap) into my dojo project (inside a dijit widget) and even debugging and seeing the filtered list in typeahead.js line 136

`(this.menuNode.innerHTML = items.join('');)`

the typeahead's items list don't show anything. No errors on console.

Any tips?

Comment: Just found out that it IS being rendered, but in a bizarre location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have lots of dijit widgets loaded vertically on my page, so I needed to edit Typeahead.js line 73 from

`domConstruct.place(this.menuNode, document.body);`

to

`domConstruct.place(this.menuNode, this.domNode.offsetParent || document.body);`

and now the menu is where it should be.

Thanks anyway!